# C# parse string and qualifier type and name of object

Tags: c#, string, parsing

i have a problem parsing a string. I looks like this:

```
#pragma section ".rtl_dpool.data" aw
int Task_C0_Event_Id;
static int Task_C1_Event_Id;
static volatile unsigned int Task_C2_Event_Id;

double PxTcpipMbx;
volatile unsigned int INITTASK___protect1;
unsigned int INITTASK___protect2;
#pragma section
```

So far I'm able to read in the complete section between #pragma section and the second #pragma section.
But now I want to get the objects inbetween and store them in a own class object.

When I have "int Task_C0_Event_Id" its easy, the first word is the type the second the name.
But how can I parse something like : "static volatile unsigned int Task_C2_Event_Id;" here I have 4 words before the Name and I need to identify them to store them correctly.

My own class could look like this:

```
class PragmaObject{

string Typequalifier;
string Type;
string ObjectName;
```

}

More or less I need something similar to what stackoverflow window does with my code, it highlights exact that information I need to sperate. Or for example in Notepad++ there also all types I would like to sperate from each other are highlited/colored by the program.

Comment: parse backwards? (last word is object name, second to last is the type, and then the others is the qualifier)

Comment: would be a option, but I don't know how to do it this way.

Comment: How does your current parsing code look? Basically, what have you tried and what didn't work about it?